# How to print output countdown number 2 turns

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input seconds => : ");
    String secs = sc.nextLine();
    int delay = 1000;
    int period = 1000;
    timer = new Timer();
    interval = Integer.parseInt(secs);
    System.out.println(secs);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(setInterval());
        }
    }, delay, period);
}

private static final int setInterval() {
    if (interval == 1)
        timer.cancel();
    return --interval;
}
```

Output : 5 4 3 2 1 0
Expect : 5 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1 0 0

ps: English is not very good ! Sorry all.
Thanks for seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below. I used a static variable **count** to print everything integer twice.

```
public class TimeCounter {
    
    static int interval;
    static Timer timer;
    static int count=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input seconds => : ");
        String secs = sc.nextLine();
        long delay = 1000;
        long period = 1000;
    
        timer = new Timer();
        interval = Integer.parseInt(secs);
        
        
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(setInterval());
            }
        }, delay, period);

    }
    
    private static final int setInterval() {
        
        
        if(interval==0) {
            timer.cancel();
            return 0;
        }
        
        if(count==2) {
            interval=interval-1;
            count=1;
        } else {
            count=count+1;
        }
        return interval;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Happy to help you ! If you are satisfied with the answer , could you please help by upvoting and accepting the answer . This is because it provides visibility.

Answer (score 0):

All the code up to `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(...)` is only executed once. You only see the numbers once, since the output is only logged via the call of your `TimerTask` repeatedly. The `Timer` then executed the `TimerTask` and every time that is executed it reduces `interval`.

Comment: yes. i'm understand this code. 
can i problem solve? help me? thanks you